# Karma config vs Protractor config files - Where to inject Angular mocks?

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e, ngmocke2e

So I'm struggling to setup a mock unit test for my Angular controllers via `Protractor`. Reason ? It's because I can't figure how to inject `Angular mocks` into my tests.

Using `Karma runner`, I have succeeded in setting this up, due to clear examples re: `karma.conf.js`; however, I need to run full e2e tests with Protractor - and I will need to inject angular controllers.

Here's an example online which demonstrates both `Karma` unit testing and `Protractor` e2d testing. https://github.com/mjhea0/angular-testing-tutorial/tree/master/tests

In karma.conf.js, you can use the `files: [ ... ]` property to specify `angular-mocks.js`, etc. However, in `protractor.conf.js` there seems to be no such thing.

Take this example that from git repo above :

```js
beforeEach(function () {
    module('myApp');
  });

  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    $scope = $rootScope.$new();
    controller = $controller('TestOneController', {
      $scope: $scope
    });
}));
```

This works when running the unit test with Karma, but how to run this with Protractor ?

It uses `module()` and `inject()`, but that using `angular-mocks.js`. Would I use `require()` to make this happen ?

Or is it somewhere along the lines that this post discusses ? http://blog.ng-book.com/how-to-mock-http-requests-in-protractor/

Advice and guidance is appreciated...

Bob